# Efficient way to migrate a wordpress webpage to a new hosting

Tags: wordpress, html

I have a website hosted in wordpress.com freely. I've got a new account on personal.website which supports wordpress. How is the easiest way to migrate the wordpress webpage to the new hosting service? I have looked for an "import" option on the personal.website dashboard without success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install **Importer plugin** in your new host. Refer this image you can export your pages or all contents as xml then, you can import them with **Importer plugin** in your new host.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ssh access to both of your website , you can use [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) method.

First you need to export the xhr file from your existing site for the page with `wp export`.

Then you can use `wp import filename` to import it via command line tools into your new server(wordpress.com)

Comment: How can I check if I have ssh access? I guess wordpress.com does, but I am not sure of personal.website. There is no much support resources on their webpage.

Comment: You can always ask to the hosting support. They will help/provide the ssh access.

Answer (score -2):

If you want more control and no downtime during the process, I suggest you see this https://thetechbarista.com/wordpress-hosting-migration-to-bluehost/

You will be copying the wp-content directory, taking a database dump and restore it on the new site. It is not mentioned in the article but indirectly you will also migrate the plugins, which are of course essential.

The article is focused on the bluehost provider, however it applies to most hosting in general.